# CSS Overflow and No Wrap Issue

Tags: jquery, css, tree, overflow, nowrap

I'm working on a tree widget that is encapsulated in a accordion.  I almost want the tree to have requirements that conflict with each other but I wanted to check and see if anyone has any ideas.

Currently, I'm applying a 'white-space:nowrap' to the text to get the folders to expand out n-deep all the way to the outer parent and then scroll so they don't wrap when they reach the max width available ( http://screencast.com/t/F7BycuaGx ).

Problem is when you have long text now, it doesn't wrap the text now ( http://screencast.com/t/bzrs5FH8r ).  I'd like the text to wrap unless it was the above scenario.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would put a inner div around the "title" with a width and reset the white-space to normal. This should limit the width of folder name and allow the depth to still grow.